# QTextEdit placeholder color

Tags: c++, css, qt, qtstylesheets

here's my problem:
I'm using Qt, I've got two QLineEdits (name, author) and one QTextEdit (description) in my form.
I need to set placeholders for each of them, so i wrote this code:

```cpp
        name->setPlaceholderText("Name");
        author->setPlaceholderText("Author");
        description->setPlaceholderText("Description");
```

Now I want to style it using QSS, thus i wrote this:

```css
    QLineEdit[text=""],
    QTextEdit[text=""] {
      color: red;
    }
```

But unfortunately this works only for QLineEdits and I cannot find a way to check if QTextEdit is empty in QSS.
Do you have any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: just for placeholder or for whole textEdit?

Comment: Just for placeholder, I have different color for typed text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is preety easy way of doing this programatically.
You can change the `QPalette` of your `QLineEdit` and `QTextEdit` and modify the `QPalette::Text` with `setColor`.

Another way of doing the same is catching signal if it is `empty` or not and setting stylesheet.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html
There is no reference of doing this in QT documentation.

If you want to look about complex examples other than this:

[Change color of placeholder text in QLineEdit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27224211/change-color-of-placeholder-text-in-qlineedit)

https://forum.qt.io/topic/90176/change-qlineedit-placeholder-text-color

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try method with catching empty signal! Still dissapointed that I can't just check if text is empty from qss, as in qlineedit. Have a good day!